# Strange issue with StackPanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm having a really strange problem with this StackPanel that I use to display images in my app. Recently, it seemed to have developed an invisible "height limit" even though it's placed inside of a ScrollViewer.

```
    <Grid x:Name="AttachmentList" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Content="Add Attachment" Height="88" Name="btnAdd" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" Click="btnAdd_Click" Margin="-12,-28,0,0" />
        <Button Content="Take Photo" Height="88" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-28,-12,0" Name="btnTakePic" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" Click="btnTakePic_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Remove Selected" Height="88" Margin="-12,48,0,0" Name="btnDelete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" Click="btnDelete_Click" />
        <Button Content="Done" Height="88" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,48,-12,0" Name="btnDone" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" Click="btnDone_Click" />
        <ScrollViewer  BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,142,0,0">
            <StackPanel Name="DisplayPanel" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </ScrollViewer> 
    </Grid>
```

Depending on the height of the images I add to it, the one image that "exceeds" this invisible limit won't be displayed (there would just be a blank space where the image should be), and all the images before or after this one would be properly displayed. Here's the code of how I'm adding the images:

```
private void imageTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
  if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
  {
    string[] splicedPath = e.OriginalFileName.Split('\\');
    string imageName = splicedPath[splicedPath.Length - 1];

    imageDict.Add(imageName, e.ChosenPhoto);

    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

    Image pic = new Image();
    pic.Source = bmp;
    pic.Tag = imageName;
    pic.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 15);
    pic.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(pic_MouseLeftButtonUp);
    DisplayPanel.Children.Add(pic);
  }
}
```

This problem didn't use to occur. In all the past versions of my app, everything still works perfectly, so I'm not sure why it's occurring now. I haven't touched the codes for this particular page for weeks. I did, however, upgrade my entire project from Windows Phone OS 7.0 to 7.1 recently. Could that be the cause? If so, what can I do to fix it?

EDIT: Finally solved the problem by putting each image in its own stack panel and adding those panels to the final display panel instead of the images on their own. Guess it's a problem with the stack panel's "limit" after all...they just can't contain that many images

Comment: Problem may be with e.ChoosenPhoto, where a certain image is not rendered properly from web service? To make sure this, add some static images of differetn heights to project and add them to static panel from code behind. Test how they are rendered.

Comment: @nkchandra I've only been testing with images stored in the phone's memory, so it shouldn't be a web service problem. Depending on the size of the images I add to the panel, the "disappearance" will occur at different times. For example, the 6th image is the one that disappears when I use images of uniform, medium height. However, if I only add tall images, the 3rd or 4th one might be the one that disappears.